# React-Native Android - Could not find com.android.tools:common

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

It seems that somehow the `android/tools/common` library has been deleted 
([pom](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.pom), [jar](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.jar)).

This caused many react native libraries that are using an old gradle version in their classpath (e.g `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3`) to not being able to sync

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update**, I had to add more code to **build.gradle**

This is my fix, I did not fork repos just used this workaround: add this to your **build.gradle** file, the sibling of **settings.gradle** file

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
     google()
     jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"}
     maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools" }
  }
}

subprojects { project ->
  def name = project.name
  if (name.contains('module name, e.g. react-native-blur')
        || name.contains('other module name, e.g. react-native-image-picker')) {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
        }
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: For your information, had to use it with react-native-image-picker and react-native-vector-icons

Answer (score 3):

In my build.gradle file (of the project not the app) i've added the new bintray url first but also had to add all the others after:

```
subprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }
            google()
            mavenLocal()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
}
```