# Gradle project sync failed. basic functionality (e.g. editing debugging) will not work properly

Tags: android, gradle

My Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing debugging) will not work properly.

I installed Android Studio and updated everything (3.2.1) , but whenever I create  new project I get these 3 errors :

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0
>
> Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3
>
> Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe connected to  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691457/react-native-android-could-not-find-com-android-toolscommon/53692168?r=SearchResults#53692168

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need a Proxy to achieve a successful Gradle sync!
Because repositories are restricted to access from IRAN.
Also you can use Shecan.ir and set your dns to the ip from this site.

If it was't about your proxy access! please share complete gradle & error here

Comment: 1 )- Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0     ////


2) - Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3 ///

3 )- Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2 ///

4 )- Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2

Comment: I changed VPN provider but didn't work so i Reinstall android studio , and  it could download dependencies. and it work.( re installation and changing Proxy made it OK)

Comment: It'll be a much better solution to set your dns by this site : https://shecan.ir/

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your build.gradle(Project) looks like this
[image]

and if not, try to change change gradle version to be as same as on this photo.
Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

i found some way for android studio 4.2

check bottom left
step 1 : find build
step 2 : you will get message sync error
step 3 : message will say to install missing gradle
step 4 : install it

and done , its work for me